# Can't convert bytes to string in python gui

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, implicit-conversion, smtplib

I'm trying to create a GUI environment which allows to send e-mails.

**I'm getting the following error:**

> Type Error: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

The GUI application gets user id, password, recipient address and the message to be sent.

What should I do?

**My code:**

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from  tkinter import *

windows=Tk()
blank=Label(windows, text="").grid(row=0,column=0)

name_id=Label(windows,text="  email id:-",font="bold 
15").grid(row=3,column=3)
pass_word=Label(windows,text="password:-",font="bold 
15").grid(row=4,column=3)

name_entry=Entry(windows,width=30)
name_entry.grid(row=3,column=4)


pass_entry=Entry(windows,width=30,show="*")
pass_entry.grid(row=4,column=4)

to_id=Label(windows,text=" to:-",font="bold 15").grid(row=5,column=3)

to_entry=Entry(windows,width=30)
to_entry.grid(row=5,column=4)

message=Label(windows,text="compose mail:-",font="bold 
14").grid(row=6,column=3)

message_box=Text(windows,width=30,height=20)
message_box.grid(row=6,column=4)

my_address=name_entry.get()
password=pass_entry.get()
to_address=to_entry.get()
msg=message_box.get("1.0",  END)


def send():
    import smtplib
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)  # type: hhh
    server.starttls()
    server.login(my_address, password)
    server.sendmail(my_address, to_address, msg)

btn=Button(windows,text="send",command=send()).grid(row=7,column=4)

windows.title("mailing app")
windows.geometry("500x500")
windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information. Which line makes problem ?

Comment: `command=` needs function name (callback) - it means without `()` - `command=send`

Comment: you have to get value from Entry in `send()`. Now you get value before `mainloop` start working - and it means before you even see window.

Comment: You probably need to call str.encode and bytes.decode, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode